# SMS integration web api consume by XML via HTTP RAW POST in c#.net

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, sms-gateway

I need to integrate send sms api using like this URL. but I am getting the message XML is incorrect format.

```
  http://<url>/action?application=msg&action=sendmsg&responsetype=xml
```

I am sending XML code like this

```
<data>
   <phone> 1234567890 </phone>
  <api_key 1234567890 </api_key>
  <message_body> This is message text </message_body>
</data>
```

My code is

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http:\\domain.com\page.asp");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "username=user";
postData += "&password=pass";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Please suggest how to resolve.**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a typo.

Add > to end of the front api_key and the balance XML needs will work.